# Zurb Foundation - Sass columns not staying in row

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm having a very basic problem getting columns to work in Foundation 4 with Sass/Compass.

At screen sizes larger than the $small media-query breakpoint (768px), I want the two columns to be of equal width (6 columns each) and beside each other. Right now, at screen sizes larger than $small, each column only occupies the left half of the page, with the second column bumping down below the first.

I've tried using Foundation's classes rather than the Sass mixins, but I'm getting the same result. I've also tried resetting to the Foundation default settings and imports, but nothing changes.

I have the following HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Sample text here.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm using the following SCSS:

```
section {
  @include grid-row;
}

.header {
  @include grid-column( 12 );
  @media #{$small} {
    @include grid-column( 6 );
  }
}

.content {
  @include grid-column( 12 );
  @media #{$small} {
    @include grid-column( 6 );
  }
}
```

And here's a link to the reduced test case: http://bit.ly/149zpEq

The red column and green column should be side-by-side at screen sizes wider than 768px. Alas, they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Use this markup without any additional sass code:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Sample text here.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Sample text here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You just need add 'large-6' and 'medium-6' for screen larger than $small and add 'small-12' for small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Sass to this.

```
.header {
  display: table-cell;
  @include grid-column( 12 );
  @media #{$small} {
    @include grid-column( 6 );
  }
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  @include grid-column( 12 );
  @media #{$small} {
    @include grid-column( 6 );
  }
}
```

display: table on it's own is not enough, child elements must have display: table-cell.

Another option would be

```
section > div{
  display: table-cell;
}
```